# Can I delete a dangling branch in my Git history if the merge is empty?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I am new to Git and have the newb following dilemma.  I moved my old svn repo to github initially by just initializing a repository full of the files from my svn repository (minus the .svn stuff).  Then, later I read that I could import my svn history, maintaining the history.  So I deleted all contents of my master branch on github and then merged it in with my imported svn master.  Then I pushed this up to github, so my commit history is something like

```
svn1 <- svn2 <- ... <- svnX <- E <- o <- o <- ... <- HEAD
                              /                        
                   A <- B <- C
```

where A is the initial commit (just copied files from svn repo), C is the where I deleted all of the stuff uploaded in A, and E is the merged of git-svn stuff and the initial repo.

So my question is, can I get rid of A through C in the history since I merged an empty directory at E?  I've been reading about git rebase, and tried several things, but nothing worked.

Thanks!
Ian

Comment: If you want to delete the branch, you can via the GUI or `git push origin :name-of-branch-to-delete`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is phylosophy. Don't create problems for yourself that you subsequently resolve. You can always start from scratch and recreate your repo on Github.

Comment: I didn't want to delete my repo because I already had a bunch of issues entered... so I'm trying to work with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Are A, B, and C already in your `master` branch?  If so, you can just go ahead and delete the branch with `git branch -d <branch>`.  If that gives you errors, you can override it by using a capital `-D`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes, A, B, C were already on a branch called "master" so I don't think I can use
"git branch -d master".